# How do you use the plugin boilerplate loader class to hook actions and filters?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

The [`Plugin_Name_Loader`](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name-loader.php) class of the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) is very useful if you must hook into a WordPress action or filter from your plugin. The original author, Tom McFarlin, says the following about [the loader](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate-3/):

> The goal of this file is to encapsulate the registration of hooks and
>   then execute both actions and filters at the appropriate time when the
>   plugin is loaded.

It is often necessary to hook into the appropriate action or filter, so how does one take advantage of the plugin boilerplate's loader class and use it to hook into actions and filters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer assumes a basic understanding of working with classes and objects. The complete answer is a bit long, so skip down to the checklist summary at the bottom if you're impatient. Read and follow the entire answer if you don't understand the summary.

---

In order to understand how to use the loader, we should look at the source for the core plugin class, `Plugin_Name` in [`class-plugin-name.php`](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php).

The [first block of code](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L32) in this class declares the private container `$loader`:

`protected $loader;`

Next, we see within [the construct](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L69) that the functions `load_dependencies` and `define_public_hooks()` are called:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->plugin_name = 'plugin-name';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    // Our fearless loader is called from within this class object.
    $this->load_dependencies();
    $this->set_locale();
    $this->define_admin_hooks();
    $this->define_public_hooks();
}
```

Following the construct, we see the function [`load_dependencies()`](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L97) defined. Here is where the resource files for classes used by the plugin are called. The first class resource file we see being [required here is `plugin-name-loader.php`](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L103).

`require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/class-plugin-name-loader.php';`

### DO THIS:

**Require any additional class files your plugin relies on within the `load_dependencies()` function.**

For example, if you have defined a class called `Plugin_Name_Alert` in the file `class-plugin-name-alert.php` located in the `includes` directory of your plugin, require it by adding this line to `load_dependencies()`:

`require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/class-plugin-name-alert.php';`

The first step is done.

---

Continuing our examination, we see that [at the end](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L122) of this function, our earlier declared container called `$loader` is now defined as a new object of the class `Plugin_Name_Loader`, which it can do now because it was just required earlier in this function:

`$this->loader = new Plugin_Name_Loader();`

Now let's skip down and take a look at [`define_public_hooks()`](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name.php#L166). This is another function that was called from the construct earlier. This is a great place to organize hooks used by your plugin. Here's how it looks:

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
    // Instantiates a new object of the class Plugin_Name_Public.
    $plugin_public = new Plugin_Name_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    // This is where the loader's add_action hooks the callback function of the class object. 
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_styles' );
    // Another action is passed to the class object.
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

You can see two important things going on here:

1. An object of a class is instantiated.
2. The loader's custom version of `add_action()` is performed which accepts the object as an argument.

This is where the loader becomes useful for us. Instead of passing just the hook and callback function to `add_action()`, the loader uses it's own custom `add_action()` and `add_filter()` functions which allow us to pass three arguments: hook, class, and callback function. This way it knows how to find the function in your class.

> While it seems more convoluted it standardizes the [addition of hooks](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/the-wordpress-plugin-boilerplate-101/) completely, splitting them into two distinct groups in the process.
> WordPress Plugin Boilerplate splits hooks into admin/public groups but that’s not all. It splits all your code in the same way by asking you to write public-facing code in the public folder and admin-facing code in the admin folder.

For reference, here are all of [the arguments accepted](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name-loader.php) by the loader's version of `add_action()`:

`add_action( $hook, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 )`

While there are ways to pass a class function to the WordPress `add_action()` or `add_filter()`, this is how you do it through the boilerplate's loader.

### DO THIS TOO:

Within the function `define_public_hooks()`, you will repeat the two steps we just examined. Remember, we can only do this because earlier we required our class file for `Plugin_Name_Alert`.

**1. Instantiate an object of your class:**

`$plugin_alert = new Plugin_Name_Alert();`

**2. Use the loader's `add_action()` to hook a function of `$plugin_alert`:**

`$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_alert, 'my_alert_function' );`

That is all. Here is a checklist to make sure you've done everything you need to.

---

## Checklist Summary

**0. Create your class.** In the above example it was defined as `Plugin_Name_Alert` at `includes/class-plugin-name-alert.php`. Here's a very simple class you can use for testing which we'll use to display an alert message every time WordPress initializes:

```
<?php

class Plugin_Name_Alert {

    public function my_alert_function() {
        ?> <script>alert("VAE VICTIS!");</script> <?php
    }

}
```

**1. Require your class within the `load_dependencies()` function.** This example used:
`require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/class-plugin-name-alert.php';`

**2. Instantiate an object of your class within the function `define_public_hooks()`.**  Here was the example:
`$plugin_alert = new Plugin_Name_Alert();`

**3. Lastly, hook the function from your class to an action or filter. Do this within `define_public_hooks()`.** Here was the example:
`$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_alert, 'my_alert_function' );`

Comment: Why is using a loader in this way superior to registering the hook within the Plugin_Name_Alert class?

Comment: Danny, thanks for the question. I have updated the answer to include a quote to briefly explain why the boilerplate does things this way. More can be found at https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/the-wordpress-plugin-boilerplate-101/

Comment: This is a very well documented answer. Thank you for sharing.